# Is it possible to have a custom label on outlook sender address?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm creating a small addin (vb.net VSTO) to distinguish emails when arriving from outside of the domain.
My question is if it is possible to have a custom label after the sender name, like in the image below? Maybe also being able to set the sender's name with a custom color.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can modify the `PR_SENDER_NAME` MAPI property, but you cannot add color:

```
YourMailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1A001F", "Test"
YourMailItem.Save
```

Comment: Mr Dmitry, do you think it is also possible to add a property to the listview on that email? I was able to add the info, but it only shows on the item itself, not on the main view.

Comment: Sure, if you expose a customer property to that message, and the property is added to the folder fields, you can add it as a column in the explorer view.